# iOS app only starting with huge delays after geo location event

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager, background-process, geofencing

At the moment I am adding geo fencing capabilities to my app. I walked through all tutorials and Apple documentation I could find and still have a huge issue. It is all basically working, but I have issues when the app or phone isn't actively being used.

In my field tests all went fine when I had optimal conditions: phone is charging and GPS is active (navigation software actively in use). The app was running in background and it behaved like I want it to.

But for the normal case like not using the phone actively when moving, it is just not working as expected. The issues seems to be that the app isn't being woken frequently enough by iOS to be able to respond to the location events.

My logs revealed that in one field test the app was not active for about 35 hours. But in these 35 hours there were several location events, which should have had woken the app to respond to them. Instead of directly responding to the events the app started (with the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey) after 35 hours inactivity and responded to all location events that iOS detected in that time frame. Great that iOS detected all these registered region transitions, but why isn't it starting my app in a reasonable time frame? It doesn't have to start it directly when the event occurs but at minimum within an hour would be acceptable for me.

Can you guys figure what I am doing wrong?

In the target's capabilities I activated "Background Modes": Location updates, Background fetch and Remote notifications.

Below some code.

This is the part where I am initializing my class for dealing with location events. The GeoManager class is handling all of that.
    @property (nonatomic) GeoManager * geoManager;
    @implementation ONEAppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    Log(LogLevelDebug, @"-application:didFinishLaunchWithOptions: called; options: %@", launchOptions);

    ...
    self.geoManager = [GeoManager sharedManager];
    return YES;
}
```

This is a bit of the GeoManager class:

```
class GeoManager : NSObject {
    class var sharedManager: GeoManager {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: GeoManager = GeoManager.init()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    private var locationManagerDelegate : LocationManagerDelegate?
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        guard UIApplication.shared.backgroundRefreshStatus == .available else {
            Log(.Info, "[GeoManager] the app isn't allowed to do background fetching.")
            return
        }
        locationManagerDelegate = LocationManagerDelegate.init(geoManager: self)
        locationManager.delegate = locationManagerDelegate
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        locationManager.activityType = .other
        Log(.Debug, "[GeoManager] initiated")
        restoreStoredFences()
    }
}
```

Registering regions like this:

```
let region = CLCircularRegion.init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: long), radius: radius, identifier: id)
region.notifyOnExit = transition == .exit
region.notifyOnEntry = transition == .enter
locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
```

This is the CLLocationManagerDelegate class:

```
class LocationManagerDelegate : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        private let geoManager : GeoManager
        init(geoManager : GeoManager) {
            self.geoManager = geoManager
            super.init()
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
            Log(.Info, "[GeoManager] Monitoring region with id \(region.identifier) succeeded")
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
            if let region = region {
                Log(.Warning, "[GeoManager] Monitoring region with id \(region.identifier) failed with error \(error)")
            } else {
                Log(.Warning, "[GeoManager] Monitoring a region failed with error \(error)")
            }
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            Log(.Info, "[GeoManager] user changed location usage authorization to \(status.rawValue)")
            if status == .authorizedAlways {
                Log(.Info, "[GeoManager] configuring geo fences because user granted permissions to use location")
                geoManager.configureFences(ONEConnectionInfo.geoData())
            }
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
            if let transition = geoManager.transitions[region.identifier], transition == .enter {
                Log(.Info, "[GeoManager] monitored region with id \(region.identifier) was entered")
                geoManager.triggerExecute(id: region.identifier)
            }
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
            if let transition = geoManager.transitions[region.identifier], transition == .exit {
                Log(.Info, "[GeoManager] monitored region with id \(region.identifier) was exited")
                geoManager.triggerExecute(id: region.identifier)
            }
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            Log(.Exception, "[GeoManager] failed to track locations with error \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe it should be these settings `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        locationManager.activityType = .other` Can you decrease the accuracy and check other activity types?

Comment: According to Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy) the setting for desiredAccuracy isn't even being considered for region monitoring:
"This property is used only in conjunction with the standard location services and is not used when monitoring significant location changes."
An if I get the docs about activityType correctly that setting also shouldn't matter, but I will try to see if anything changes with other settings.

Comment: @Kai - thats correct. did you already find a workaround? I used a kind of silent push to handle my own exit event. Due to some issues in iOS11, I'd like to find a more suitable solution....

Comment: @AlexWoe89 sadly I haven't found a solution yet. But for me it looks like iOS 11 made it even worse!

Comment: @Kai I am having this same issue. Any solution yet? I tried with activityTypeFitness, with a thought that Fitness related data would be more frequent. But no luck

Comment: Hey @Nil , no I don't have a solution yet. But my colleague may have a lead. Will post it here if there is improvement.

Comment: @Kai thanx, looking forward to it.

Comment: @Kai I am having same issue like delay in geofence enter/exit event fire more than 1 hour.if you found any solution then pls post it.

Comment: @Kai did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Nil Sorry but we dropped the geo fencing feature in our app for now, because we couldn't find a good working solution for this problem.